# How to retrieve SVN files listing from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, svn, powershell-7.0

How can I retrieve the list of files from a given SVN repository from PowerShell?

For the sake of demonstration, let's assume `svn://example.com/repo` is the path to my repository.

I can do it directly from the console (both the regular Windows terminal and PowerShell):

```
svn list svn://example.com/repo
```

This will output the list of files directly within that directory.

In PowerShell, I thought it would be as straightforward as this (using a method to get the full SVN command on my search path [described on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/676107/139558)):

```
$svnCommand = (Get-Command svn).Path
&$svnCommand list svn://example.com/repo | Out-Host
```

However, this yields no (i.e. zero lines of) output. Adding or removing the `--xml` flag makes no difference (with the flag, I'm getting the skeleton of an otherwise empty file listing Xml document).

Using other commands such as `svn info`, I can confirm that the general mode of calling seems to be ok, because output does appear if I run e.g.

```
&$svnCommand info svn://example.com/repo | Out-Host
```

This also *seems* to rule out authentication issues, for `svn info` returns some information such as the last change author that I should only be privy to if I have read access to the target repo.

So, what is the issue with `svn list`?

Comment: On a side note, when `Get-Command` finds `svn`, then you can just call `svn` without specifying the full path (and without having to use the call operator `&`).

Comment: @zett42: Hmm, that's right. I must have been misled by my repeated script-changing and retrying to think that using just `svn` wouldn't work.